# onItemClickListener for multiple AutoCompleteTextView

Tags: android

I have three AutoCompleteTextView and set onItemClickListener to it,would you please help me for know which AutoCompleteTextView is clicked

```
public class ProductMainListViewer extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {

    CustomerDataBaseAdapter customerDataBaseAdapter;
    AutoCompleteTextView txtUserName;
    AutoCompleteTextView txtContactNo;
    AutoCompleteTextView txtSearchProduct;
    TextView txtDateAndTime;
    TextView txtQty;
    TextView txtSalePrize;
    TextView txtRunit;
    TextView txtWunit;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_product_main_list_viewer);
        customerDataBaseAdapter = new CustomerDataBaseAdapter(this);
        customerDataBaseAdapter = customerDataBaseAdapter.open();
        ArrayList<Customer> customers = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<ProductsDetails> productsDetails = new ArrayList<>();

        try {
            customers = customerDataBaseAdapter.getCustomerList();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            productsDetails = customerDataBaseAdapter.getProductList();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        txtUserName = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.editTextUserNamecheck);
        CustomArrayAdapterAutoCmplt adapter1 = new CustomArrayAdapterAutoCmplt(this, R.layout.activity_auto_cmplt_custom, customers);
        txtUserName.setThreshold(1);
        txtUserName.setAdapter(adapter1);
        txtUserName.setOnItemClickListener(this);

        txtContactNo = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.editTextPhoneNoNew);
        CustomPhoneArrayAdapterAutoCmplt adapter2 = new CustomPhoneArrayAdapterAutoCmplt(this, R.layout.activity_auto_cmplt_custom, customers);
        txtContactNo.setThreshold(1);
        txtContactNo.setAdapter(adapter2);
        txtContactNo.setOnItemClickListener(this);

        txtSearchProduct = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.searchProduct);
        ProductAutoCmplt adapter3 = new ProductAutoCmplt(this, R.layout.activity_auto_cmplt_custom, productsDetails);
        txtSearchProduct.setThreshold(1);
        txtSearchProduct.setAdapter(adapter3);
        txtSearchProduct.setOnItemClickListener(this);
        txtDateAndTime = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.dateAndTime);
        txtQty = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtQty);
        txtSalePrize = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtPrize);
        txtRunit = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtRUnit);
        txtWunit = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtWUnit);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });


    }


    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        try {
            if (txtUserName.getText().equals("")) {
                Customer item = (Customer) txtContactNo.getAdapter().getItem(position);
                txtUserName.setText(item.getMember_name());

            } else {
                Customer item = (Customer) txtUserName.getAdapter().getItem(position);
                txtContactNo.setText(item.getContactType());
            }

            DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy  'at' HH:mm:ss ");
            String date = df.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
            txtDateAndTime.setText(date);

        } catch (Exception e) {
        }


    }



}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in onItemClick you can identify the Adapter AdapterView parent so you can identify first the parent adapter .

something like below

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    if (parent.getAdapter().getClass().equals(ProductAutoCmplt .class)) {
      //do your stuff
    }
    else if(parent.getAdapter().getClass().equals(CustomPhoneArrayAdapterAutoCmplt .class)){ 
//do your stuff
}else if(parent.getAdapter().getClass().equals(CustomArrayAdapterAutoCmplt.class)){
//do your stuff
}
}
```

Comment: yesssssss..................It's working perfectly,Thank you so munch #Damodhar Meshram  you saved my time

Comment: what we can do if we have same adapter class ?

Comment: @RujulGandhi This solution will work with the same adapter class also, just need to make sure we have a separate instance of adapter.

Answer (score 2):

check using `View` parameter of `onItemClick` compare view id. like below

```
if(view.getId() == R.id.editTextUserNamecheck){

 }else if(view.getId() == R.id.editTextPhoneNoNew){

 }else if(view.getId() == R.id.searchProduct){
 }
```

use above code inside `public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)`

Comment: :-This method is not working because view.getid() return -1 for all the AutoCompleteTextView

Comment: then use diffrent event for all

Comment: in my case view.getId() is same all the time and can't compare using switch of if-else

Answer (score 0):

using anonymous inner classes, we can do it as follows :

```
txtUserName.setOnItemClickListener((new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            // do your stuff;
        }
    });                              

txtContactNo.setOnItemClickListener((new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            // do your stuff;
        }
    });                          

txtSearchProduct.setOnItemClickListener((new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            // do your stuff;
        }
    });
```